# Stability in a double-pole system

Tags: dc-dc-converter, control-system, stability, bode-plot, pole-zeroplot

A simple low-pass RC circuit is a single pole system and it's stable. In a DC-DC buck converter, we have a conjugate double pole due to the LC filter. Yet, we employ several techniques such as D-CAP or Type I/II/III compensation. Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you add feedback around the native double pole system. This makes the characteristics of the system different from those of the L.C alone, and necessitates loop compensation.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: A passive 3-pole or 4-pole system without feedback is always stable. Only feedback can make a system unstable (intentionally or not). Self-excitement is possible with feedback only.

Comment: So, for proper regulation at the output end, we add a feedback loop and that basically gives a -360° phase shift and the circuit starts to oscillate. So we need some sort of compensation to avoid this, right?